# different results in visual studio and linux(eclipse)

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, c++

my code works perfectly in visual studio yet i encounter a problem running it in eclipse.
in the function:

```
City* Gps::FindCity(const char* city)  
 {  
 if(city != NULL)
 {  
      City *tmp = NULL;  
      if (! m_gpsCities.empty())  
      {  
           for (list<City*>::iterator iter = m_gpsCities.begin(); iter != m_gpsCities.end(); iter++) 
           {  
                tmp = (City*)(*iter);  
                if(Vehicle::StringCompare(tmp->GetCityName(),city)==0)  
                return tmp;    
           }  
      }  
 }  
 return NULL;  
}
```

the problem is, that after the first iteration, and while the list has more then 1 elements, it exits the loop, and doesn't go over the other elements in the list.

stringcompare:

```
 int Vehicle::StringCompare(const char* str1, const char* str2)//assuming all not null  
 {  
    string s1, s2;  
    char *st1 = OrgName(str1),*st2 = OrgName(str2);  

    s1.assign(st1);  
    s2.assign(st2);  

    int size1 = s1.size(), size2 = s2.size(), min = 0, index =0;  

    if(str1[size1 - 1] == '\r' || str1[size1 - 1] == '\0' || str1[size1 - 1] == '\n')  
        size1--;  
    if(str2[size2 - 1] == '\r' || str2[size2 - 1] == '\0' || str2[size2 - 1] == '\n')  
        size2--;  

    if(size1>size2)  
        min=size2;  
    else  
        min=size1;  

    bool bigger1 = true;  
    for(index=0;index<min;index++)  
    {  
        if(st1[index]>st2[index])  
            return 1;  
        if(st1[index]<st2[index])  
            return (-1);  
    }  

    delete[] st1;  
    delete[] st2;  

    if(size1==size2)  
        return 0;  
    if(min==size1)  
       return (-1);  
    else  
        return 1;  
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Vehicle::StringCompare(tmp->GetCityName(),city)==0` returned true?

Comment: Why is `StringCompare` a member function of `Vehicle`?

Comment: it didnt return true, cause while i debugg i see that it returns to the loop line after the first iteration.

Comment: it's part of a home work assignment, i chose to place the function in vehicle cause it's the most basic object

Comment: Indent your code properly. ;)

Comment: @shiran bar : "cause while i debugg i see that it returns to the loop..." No connection here, some debuggers are bugged. When I used gcc with gdb the debugger used to jump back and forth before returning from a function. I don't know who to blame though (bad debug info? badly designed format? ...).

Comment: the comparision returns false, and thanks i didnt know that about the debugger

Comment: @shiran bar, can you post the code for Vehicle::StringCompare?  If I was a betting man, I'd bet a nickel that StringCompare is returning 0 and that's why it's returning.

Comment: it doesn't i tries inserting the comparision result to a variable and it showed that it was 1 not 0

Comment: @shiran bar, have you tried assigning `m_gpsCities.size()` to a variable (or whatever method is convenient in Eclipse), before entering the for-loop, to make sure there is more than one element in the list.

Comment: i realized now, that i didn't interpret correctly what the debugger showed on the screen, and it was actually a 1-element list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to achieve [`find_if`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/find_if.html) for your specific predicate, which is indeed a variant of `strcmp` with less specific integer output. Try this:

```
City* Gps::FindCity(const char* MyCityName)  
{  
    if((MyCityName!= NULL)&&(!m_gpsCities.empty())
    {  
        for (list<City*>::const_iterator iter=m_gpsCities.begin(); iter!=m_gpsCities.end(); ++iter)
        {  
            const char* MyCityTempNameChar = iter->GetCityName();
            const char * st1 = OrgName(MyCityName),
            const char * st2 = OrgName(MyCityTempName);  
            const int predicate = strcmp(st1, st2);
            if(predicate==0)
            {  
                return (*iter);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    return NULL;  
}
```

Or adapt the predicate according to the following:

```
 int Vehicle::StringCompare(const char* str1, const char* str2)
 {  
    const char * st1 = OrgName(str1),
    const char * st2 = OrgName(str2);  
    const int predicate = strcmp(st1, st2);
    return predicate; 
 }
```

Comment: but i need to use my comparison, i compare it in a certain way.

Comment: It seems you just compare two city names.

Comment: i do it in a specific way that was requested